# Do the triple-quoted (docstring) messages in Python appear while typing in IDEs other than IDLE?

Tags: python, ide, python-idle

I usually write scripts to calculate or process things for my own consumption. Now I'm trying to write scripts for others.

I use both IDLE and a terminal, but I like just like the IDLE interface and find it more helpful. Today I "discovered" that I can add triple-quoted text under `class` and `def` and see them in real time when using IDLE, and I realize I can use those to help others know how to use these classes and methods.

But if run from a terminal this is all lost.

**Question:** Is it only IDLE users who are seeing these cues *while they are typing a line that uses the class or method*, or is this something that people using terminal *could see while typing if they wanted to?* I know that one could type `A.__doc__` to see it for example, but the pop-up window is really convenient and helpful.

```
class A(object):
    """hey A!"""

    def __init__(self, x):
        """hey __int__!"""

        self.x = x

    def sqrx(self):
        """hey sqrx!"""

        print self.x**2
```

[image]

[image] (just to see what would happen if)

[image]

But if I do this from a terminal all these prompts disappear.

[image] nothing.

Comment: I don't think you can do something like pop up in terminals because Python REPL is thinked to work with terminals and if this one doesn't give features that it can use for creating suggestion in pop up/notifications than REPL can't. And I'm sure that basic terminal like _**cmd**_ and _**bash**_ don't have some feature for this.

Comment: It's an IDE thing. Dumb terminals generally don't.

Answer (score 2):

The "triple-quoted messages" are [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), and they appear in different contexts.

For example:

- When hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> (or whatever key is bound to the "[Quick Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-reference-information.html)" action) in PyCharm:

  [image]

  There is also an option to display the quick documentation pop-up while typing.
- When calling `help` on the function:

  ```
  >> help(foo)
  Help on function foo in module __main__:

  foo()
       foo's docstring
  ```

I can not tell you about other IDEs as I don't use them.