# How to selectively override the text from python's help(MYclass) with something shorter and customized?

Tags: python, python-2.7, docstring

I'm learning to write user-friendly classes and methods and I'd like for users to know how to use them from a terminal. Python's standard `help(MYclass)` returns eighteen lines I don't want, and that's half a screen for a small window and those just learning python will lose continuity with the previous lines disappearing from the top.

Is there any way I can override what using `help(MYclass)` (or `help(MYmethod)`) shows so that it only displays the (in this case) one-line docstring?

While some IDEs show the docstrings in bubbles, terminals don't cooperate. ([Do the triple-quoted (docstring) messages in Python appear while typing in IDEs other than IDLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53988820/3904031)):

[image]

So instead, I've turned to `help` for help, but `help` is *overly helpful* with all those extra lines of template.

Then I thought of redefining help:

```
def hhelp(x):
    return x.__doc__
help = hhelp
```

but I decided that this is evil; like redefining the number 7, and I would like `help(some builtin)` to still work normally, and the selective hijacking to occur only for `MYclass`es.

There is always

```
def doc(x):
    return x.__doc__
```

if I can't find anything that selectively hijacks `help()`.

---

```
class A(object):
    """instantiate a = A(x), then use a.sqr() to get x**2"""
    def __init__(self, x):
            self.x = x
    def sqr(self):
            return x**2
```

results in nineteen lines. I'd only like my one-line docstring to show.

```
Help on class A in module __main__:

class A(__builtin__.object)
 |  instantiate a = A(x), then use a.sqr() to get x**2
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __init__(self, x)
 |  
 |  sqr(self)
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __dict__
 |      dictionary for instance variables (if defined)
 |  
 |  __weakref__
 |      list of weak references to the object (if defined)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monkeypatch the built-in `help` function to show the `__doc__` string for classes and to fall back on the original `help` for other objects:

```
import inspect
import pydoc

class Helper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.help = __builtins__.help

    def __call__(self, obj):
        if inspect.isclass(obj):
            return pydoc.pager(obj.__doc__)
        else:
            return self.help(obj)

__builtins__.help = Helper()
```

Which produces the following output:

```
class Foo:
    """This is the docstring."""

    def foo(self):
        return None

help(Foo)

# Output:
# This is the docstring.
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I need, thank you! If I take some time to stop and smell the bananas I could probably come up with some way to "refine the monkey" to handle my classes but leave things like `list` alone.

Comment: @uhoh You could use `inspect.isclass(obj) and not any(map(lambda x: x is obj, (list, tuple, set, dict, ...)))` or if you have all your classes inherit from some custom base class `MyBase` you could use `issubclass(obj, MyBase)`. To be more complete on the above enumeration you could also use `map(lambda x: getattr(__builtins__, x), dir(__builtins__)` to obtain a full list of built-in objects.

Comment: I was in the middle of formulating a new question on just that, I'll plug those in to my unfinished abstracted script to see if you have pre-answered it. I'll flag you here if I decide to go ahead with the post. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

As `help(help)` indicates it relies on [`pydoc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pydoc.html), specifically `pydoc.help`.

> |  Define the builtin 'help'.
>    |  This is a wrapper around pydoc.help (with a twist).

Inspecting the source code we find that it relies on `TextDoc.docclass` to generate the help text for classes. So we can monkeypatch that method in order to generate our own help text:<sup>1</sup>

```
import pydoc

def docclass(self, object, *args, **kwargs):
    return pydoc.getdoc(object)

pydoc.TextDoc.docclass = docclass
```

Now we'll only get the `__doc__` string in the help text:

```
class Foo:
    """This is the docstring."""

    def foo(self):
        return None

help(Foo)

# Output:
# Help on class Foo in module __main__:
# 
# This is the docstring.
```

---

<sub>1. The syntax is specific to Python 2.7 since the OP uses the corresponding tag. Though it seems to work with other versions of Python as well.</sub>

Comment: Thanks also for the explanation. I learned some useful things today, yay!